# Is there any custom app for Dashboard to display initiatives that teams are working and to see features under initiatives?

Tags: rally

1. I found one custom app **Features map** in RALLY GitHub which shows capabilities to features or Is there any app that shows only initiatives to features.
2. Can someone help me in the code to show initiatives in the place of capabilities and also not showing user stories as well.

This is the link for the **Features map**
https://github.com/CustomAgile/FeatureMap/blob/master/deploy/App.html